# Permission denied when activating virtual env in python in container commands, Elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a deployed django app in aws elastic beanstalk. I wanted to run `python manage.py migrate` to initialize the database and create a table. I am using RDS mysql database.

To achieve what I want, I have written container commands

```
container_commands:
  01_migrations:
    command: |
      $PYTHONPATH/activate    # **error**
      python3 manage.py makemigrations
      python3 manage.py migrate
    leader_only: true
```

Error comes when activating virtual environment. The python path is correct and stored in the env variables.

Logs from `cfn-init-cmd.logs`

```
2023-04-28 14:03:47,881 P2563 [INFO] Command 01_migrations
2023-04-28 14:03:47,908 P2563 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]    /bin/sh: /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate: Permission denied
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]    Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]      File "manage.py", line 11, in main
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]    
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]    
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]    Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]      File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]        main()
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]      File "manage.py", line 17, in main
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]        ) from exc
2023-04-28 14:03:47,909 P2563 [INFO]    ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

How to set permissions inorder to successfully activate the virtual environment?